# Check a set of environment variables in process.env is defined, and never again

Tags: typescript

My program requires a largish set of environment variables to be set. I want to check for these at startup, and never again. I don't want to extract their values to other variables; I want to reference them in my code as `process.env.VAR` thereafter, so that it's clear that they're environment variables.

```js
const requiredEnvironmentVariables = ["FOO", "BAR"] as const;

for (const variable of requiredEnvironmentVariables) {
  if (!process.env[variable]) {
    // env1 has type string | undefined
    const env1 = process.env[variable];
    throw new Error(`Required environment variable is not set: ${variable}`);
  }
  
  // env2 has type string | undefined
  const env2 = process.env[variable];
}

// foo has type string | undefined
const foo = process.env.FOO;

if (!process.env.BAR) {
  throw new Error("Required environment variable is not set: BAR");
}

// bar has type string
const bar = process.env.BAR;
```

If I check undefinedness for a variable separately (`BAR`), TypeScript correctly narrows its type to `string`. If I check using dynamic property access (using static keys), TypeScript is not able to narrow it down.

I'm using TypeScript 4.2.2 and `@types/node` 14.14.10.

`process.env` has type `ProcessEnv`.

```
interface ProcessEnv extends Dict<string> {}
interface Dict<T> {
    [key: string]: T | undefined;
}
```

- In the above, *why* does TypeScript not narrow the types of `env2` and `foo` to be `string`? Why does `env1` not have type `undefined`?
- *How* can I make it do so?

Comment: I'd guess it's related to the loop - it's narrowed *inside*, but (perhaps because the object could be updated in another iteration) not *outside*. Example: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.2.2#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgGIHt3IN4ChnIDaA1hAJ4BcyAzmFKAOYC6Vt9IDyAPsgK4gATCDFAQBAblwBfXLgToQtZDCoYsAXhxTJuGOijIAFABsIYZAH1koIgAYmAShz5rMIwEIYhAEQAjOFDejs4EBGAAFlDoAO7IIBCxAKJQUVCG3gLA1P4pYt4OkgQyBDAAdDmlYOgAMjHQAMJw1BCGBdKyZRVVtdENTS1tQA

Comment: That makes a lot of sense. However, in my example, `env2` is *not* narrowed, and it's clear `variable` does not change value.

Comment: I mean because `process.env` could change inside a loop, in general; there's a limit to how much analysis the compiler will do.